# android - reading user created file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, file, io

Couldn't find too much about how to read a file that isn't somewhere on the SD card or storage, but rather right there in the android project directory.

I keep getting a **FileNotFoundException**. This is how I declare the file,

```
File SPPolicy = new File("SHPR_policy");
```

I've gotten the same error when putting it in the *src/ directory*, the *src/[[package]]/ directory* and the main project directory, and I get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /SHPR_policy: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or  directory)
```

Is there a certain place I have to put this file? Is it because my file doesn't have an extension (I noticed the "/" before SHPR_policy but I didn't think it would be a problem because **Eclipse** let me create a file without an extension)?

Comment: It should be in the **assets** folder, not in **src/somewhere**

Comment: are you creating the file during runtime? then you cannot place it in assets.

Comment: No, it's meant to be a constant file. I will put it in assets and see how that works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file in raw folder and try the below code.

```
 try
 {
        Resources res = getResources();
        InputStream in_s = res.openRawResource(R.raw.test);

        byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];
        in_s.read(b);
        txtHelp.setText(new String(b));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        txtHelp.setText("errr.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these piece of code to check if the file was already created:

```
File f;
f=new File("myfile");
if(!f.exists()){
  f.createNewFile();
}
```

Also, if you want to allocate your file in the external directory you can use these code:

```
File newxmlfile = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/new.xml");
XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
try {
   newxmlfile.createNewFile();
} catch (Exception e) {
   Log.e("IOException", "exception in createNewFile() method", e);
}
```

And, did you added the permission in the manifest to be able to manipulate files?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place the file in the assets folder and use this:

```
   InputStream ims = getAssets().open("SHPR_policy");
```